# Scattering processes in $\rm Au$ and $\rm AuPd$

Tags: solid-state-physics, metals, transport-phenomena

I'm learning about the transport of electrons in solids (especially based on the Drude model), and I was wondering how the different scattering processes that take place in metals vary with temperature.

Speciffically, I would like to know what scattering processes are dominant in $\rm Au$ and in an alloy such as $\rm AuPd$ (50/50) for instance and why. Do you know about any references I could consult?

Comment: In ideal single crystals, or in actual engineering materials?

Comment: In ideal single crystals.